# How to assert sinon mongoose stubs

Tags: javascript, sinon

Having a unit test case that uses a mongoose Model that was stubed, I need to ensure that authModel.create was called. How to assert that?

My unit test:

```js
     const createUserStub = sinon.stub(authModel, 'create')
            .resolves(userContent)

        return request(app).post('/auth/create')
            .send(userContent)
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect((response) => {
                const apiResponse = JSON.parse(response.text)

                expect(createUserStub.calledOnce).to.equal(true)
                expect(apiResponse).to.be.an('Object')
                expect(apiResponse).to.have.property('_id')
                expect(apiResponse).to.have.property('name')
                expect(apiResponse).to.have.property('last_name')
                expect(response.res.statusCode).to.equal(200)
            }).end(done)
```

On the first expect assertion always returns false.

Comment: Hi, which version of sinon are you using? I think you need to check `called` property instead of `calledOnce` ( calledOnce is a property of sinon.spy ).

```
expect(createUserStub.called).to.equal(true)
```

should works.

Thanks!

Comment: It solved my problem. I didn't know that calledOnce is a property of sinon.spy.
Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! I will post as answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check called property instead of calledOnce ( calledOnce is a property of sinon.spy ).

```
expect(createUserStub.called).to.equal(true)
```

should works. Thanks!